# How to convert a series of index/category, into a classification array

Tags: python, numpy

How, to convert a series of indexes, into a 2-D array which expresses the category/classifier that's defined by the indexes values in list ?

e.g.:

```
import numpy as np

aList = [0,1,0,2]
anArray = np.array(aList)

resultArray = convertToCategories(anArray)
```

and the return value of `convertToCategories()` would be like:

```
[[1,0,0],             # the 0th element of aList is index category 0
[0,1,0],              # the 1st element of aList is index category 1
[1,0,0],              # the 2nd element of aList is index category 0
[0,0,1]]              # the 3rd element of aList is index category 2
```

In last resort, I could of course:

- parse the list,
- count the number of categories (it's contiguous/continuous, it could be simply to find the maximum)
- create a zeroed array with the good size found
- then reparse the list, so as to fill the array according the indices given by the list, with 1 (or True).

But I am wondering if there exists a more pythonic, or dedicated numpy, or pandas function to achieve this kind of transformation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this -

```
import numpy as np

# Size parameters
N = anArray.size
M = anArray.max()+1

# Setup output array
resultArray = np.zeros((N,M),int)

# Find out the linear indices where 1s would be put
idx =  (np.arange(N)*M) + anArray

# Finally, put 1s at those places for the final output
resultArray.ravel()[idx] = 1
```

Sample run -

```
In [188]: anArray
Out[188]: array([0, 1, 0, 2, 4, 1, 3])

In [189]: resultArray
Out[189]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Or, better just directly index into the output array with the row and column indices -

```
# Setup output array and put 1s at places indexed by row and column indices.
# Here, anArray would be the column indices and [0,1,....N-1] would be the row indices 
resultArray = np.zeros((N,M),int)
resultArray[np.arange(N),anArray] = 1
```

Comment: @StephaneRolland Yeah, that strike me after I posted the first approach, less hassle with it.